# Mysql query issue that returns wrong SUM

Tags: mysql, sql

please help me with this query.. It seems simple but read below to see:
Query:

```
select SUM(price) 
from prices_adverts 
where advert_id="1" 
  and room_type_id="2" 
  and (date >= "2013-10-10" 
  AND date <"2013-10-13") 
order by price
```

this query checks for price for hotel room for period between above dates. In this case for 2 days - `2013-10-10` and `2013-10-11`. I have setted in the database price for `2013-10-10 - 34 euro` and price `2013-10-11 - 0.00euro`.

How I can make the query to return 0.00 price if even 1 day in the period has price 0.00?

I use this 0.00 value to show later that the room is not available for the specific date.. Now this query returns eur 34 as sum which is the price only for 1 day 2013-10-10 because the second day the room is not available..

I hope you understand the nature of the issue

Comment: There's an aggregating function but no GROUP BY clause. Shurely shome mishtake.

Comment: @Strawberry you can have a agg func without no grouping ... but the `order by` makes no sense

Comment: order by is indeed not needed. Neither is grouping - when you don't have one it just performs a sum, not a sum per group, no issue here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select if(min(price)=0, 0, SUM(price) )
from prices_adverts 
where advert_id="1" 
  and room_type_id="2" 
  and (date >= "2013-10-10" 
  AND date <"2013-10-13") 
order by price
```

Comment: if you use case when instead of if, it will work on other databases as well.

Comment: AdrianBR - you saved my day man ! Genious ! Thanks, I accept your answer and will vote for it in 3 minutes :)

Comment: @Quandary 'if' is much more cleaner visually, I like to use that for mysql. It's a statement designed for a single option case.